# Add another author name without displaying on sidebar

Tags: beamer

I am making a beamer presentation using the Berkeley theme, and I want to add another author's name on the title frame, but not display it on the sidebar, I only want the display the first author's name to display on the sidebar with the second author's name on the title frame

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Berkeley}

\title{Presentation Name}
\author{First Author's Name\\
Second Author's Name
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the short option: `\author[First author]{Both authors}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sigur has already stated in a comment, the `\author` macro takes an optional argument (encased in square brackets before the main argument), which can be used to display a "short author" field in, for instance, the left-hand sidebar.

I don't know which scholarly field you're in, but in mine (economics) and in many others I'm familar with, it is very much frowned upon -- or, in fact, simply unthinkable -- to show just one author if a piece or beamer presentation has been co-authored by two persons. If you really need to conserve space in the sidebar, I'd resort to coming up with a short title for display in the sidebar before deciding to show just one author name. E.g., instead of

```
\title{A Presentation of Some Eccentric Thoughts}
\author[J. Jardine]{Jill Jardine \and Samantha Smith}
```

I would try

```
\title[Thoughts]{A Presentation of Some Eccentric Thoughts}
\author[Jardine \& Smith]{Jill Jardine \and Samantha Smith}
```

Comment: To answer your concern about the co-authored presentation, I'm using the additional space for additional titles about the first author and the sidebar for only to display the name of the author